# How to split list at exact string?

Tags: list-manipulation

```
str = {"a", "b", "---", "c", "d", "e", "---", "f"}
```

I want to make it split at `"---"`.

The result should be:

```
{{"a", "b"}, {"c", "d", "e"}, {"f"}}
```

How to do that?

Comment: `SplitBy[str, # == "---" &] /. "---" :> (## &[]) /. {} -> Sequence[]`?

Comment: @kglr why not directly `SplitBy[str, # == "---" &] /. {"---"} :> Sequence[]`?

Comment: @corey979 Yes.Thank you very much